# How to edit this code to make it use the current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, symfony

I'm working on Symfony project, so I have a form that is generated by data-prototype. Basically is a form with 6 inputs, and I have a function that takes values of `date.input` and `duration.input` and must calculate a endingDate and paste it in a `<h5>`.

So, this form can be generated as many times as you want, and all inputs have same structure, like  `loan_charges_1_date, loan_charges_1_duration` ... next one will be with same id, except the number... `loan_charges_2_date`... or any other number.

I implemented a script that is collecting all id's of date inputs, and all of duration, and make a array that contain this values in pair, like

```
pairs = [
[loan_charge_1_date, loan_charge_1_duration],
[loan_charge_2_date, loan_charge_2_duration],
[loan_charge_151_date, loan_charge_151_duration],
[loan_charge_302_date, loan_charge_302_duration],
];
```

From my requirements, each generated form is a table row with inputs in td.
First I introduce the date, then duration, and `onkeyup` of introducing duration, it must `.html()` (for now) value of date input, but from this form.

What I have now is that it works with `.last.html(dateValue);`, which makes me problem, cause if I generate at once more than 1 additional form, and start fill the first one, `the hint h5 of output` of LAST form is filled. Or if I fill forms one-by-one, but after that I want to edit a date or duration of previous form inputs, it will show a result not at current hint, but at the last one.

Please, watch my JSFiddle code with comments : https://jsfiddle.net/x2j72xou/3/  (but it is impossible to sent all the code, cause it's from many files and it's rendered from Symfony, and so on). A screenshot how it is now you can see here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQt2P.jpg

How it is possible to detect the index or id of each input was changed, and based on it, to fill that `h5` hint, not the last one?

Thank you!

Comment: Source of the html is completely irrelevant...the browser doesn't care. Really hard to make much sense out of exactly what you are trying to do or what the specific problem is

Comment: Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: There is no need to watch in HTML, cause all that is important in HTML are just ID's which are generated, and I explained that. All the stuff is in JS script. It aproximative makes all that needs, except that I can't make it to display a hint in the same form, just in the last one...but from that appears some bugs cases.
I need a way to modify my second part of JS code. I need to introduce one more value in pairs array, the value of id/index of which input was changed, So I will can use this index/id to display hint in current form, not in the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating the whole thing with those arrays and trying to use id selectors

Can do it something like:

```
// assign input event listener to date and duration <input>s
$('input[id$="_duration"], input[id$="_date"]').on('input', function(event){
   // `this` is matching element that the event occurred on       
   // work within each row instance
   let $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
       // find() the inputs in this row       
       $durInput = $row.find('input[id$="_duration"]'),
       startDate = $row.find('input[id$="_date"]').val(),
       duration =  $durInput.val();
       // do some validation before proceeding
       if(!startDate || ! duration){
         return;
       }

      let endDate = calcEndDate(startDate, duration);     
       // add the <h5> if it isn't there yet
       if(!$durInput.siblings('h5').length){
          $durInput.after("<h5></h5>")
       } 

       $durInput.siblings('h5').text(endDate)
});

function calcEndDate(startDate, duration){
   // do whatever needed , returning start for now
   return startDate

}
```

The important part of any repeating components such as this is to work within the main repeating container...in this case each `<tr>`

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gbqexdh5/)**</kbd>

Comment: U are my hero. I spend 2 days and a lot of algorithms to solve it, but u made it in just some lines.... Can you please finish the idea, I want script to work 100% right, so on change of date or duration, the script to be running and to return value. I mean ... if I introduced 01/01/2000 and duration 10, and after that i changed not date, but duration, script to make re-calculations.
So, on every change on duration input, to run the calcEndDate()

Comment: it will do that already if either is changed. You simply need to do the date calcs (and date validation ) and return updated string in `calcEndDate()`.

Comment: Thank you, master :) I reviewed all code and understand how it works, so ... now I'm feeling better :) The last thing that i wanna know : how to add some regex to select, find inputs not just by _duration and _date structure, cause in my code I have some other forms that match it, i want it to match charges_integer_duration like (loan_charges_1363_duration)

Comment: Use classes on common elements and use those classes as selectors. As for the other issues. Start new question(s)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why you're making those pairs first, but it seems that you're only doing this so you know which date belongs to which duration. You don't really need to do that though, since you can easily find the matching elements inside the event handler. You know that the element that triggered the event is a duration input, so you just need to find the date input that is in the same row.

I've made an example below that does just that. I've stripped down your code to a bare minimum for running this snippet.
You also say that you can make a lot of these rows and I'm not sure if you mean to do this dynamically, so just to be safe I delegated the events.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', '.loan_charges_duration', function() {
    var $duration = $(this);// this is your duration input for this row
    var $row = $duration.closest('tr');
    var $date = $row.find('.loan_charges_date');// this is your date input for this row

    // check for an h5 element after duration, else create and insert it
    var $h5 = $duration.next('h5');
    if ($h5.length==0) {
      $h5 = $('<h5>').insertAfter($duration);
    }
    
    // set the html of the h5 element for this row
    $h5.html('date: '+$date.val()+' | duration: '+$duration.val());
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h5 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <label for="loan_charges_0_date">Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="loan_charges_0_date" name="loan[charges][0][date]" class="form-control loan_charges_date" value="13/12/2001">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="loan_charges_0_duration">Duration</label>
      <input type="text" id="loan_charges_0_duration" name="loan[charges][0][duration]" class="form-control loan_charges_duration" value="11">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <label for="loan_charges_1_date">Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_date" name="loan[charges][1][date]" class="form-control loan_charges_date" value="01/01/2001">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="loan_charges_1_duration">Duration</label>
      <input type="text" id="loan_charges_1_duration" name="loan[charges][1][duration]" class="form-control loan_charges_duration" value="24">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td coslpan="3">...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>151</td>
    <td>
      <label for="loan_charges_151_date">Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="loan_charges_151_date" name="loan[charges][151][date]" class="form-control loan_charges_date">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="loan_charges_151_duration">Duration</label>
      <input type="text" id="loan_charges_151_duration" name="loan[charges][151][duration]" class="form-control loan_charges_duration">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```